# Galeria vertical en css con scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

Necesito crear esta galeria, ya tengo el div con el scroll, pero aun no puedo crear las miniaturas y que se haga scroll cuando seleccione otra imagen de la miniatura [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que tengo, solo es un div,

```
    <div class=" col-md-5 mx-auto gallery-res" >
        <div class="anyClass bg-gray" style="max-height: 800px;">

            <div class="btn-center mt-5">
                <img width="80%" src="../img/cc1.jpg" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="btn-center mt-2">
                <img width="80%" src="../img/cc2.jpg" alt="">

            </div>

            <div class="btn-center mt-2">
                <img width="80%" src="../img/cc3.jpg" alt="">

            </div>

            

        </div>
    </div>
```

y esto es mi css con el div, pero aun no se como agregar las miniaturas

```
    .anyClass {
     height:90%;
     overflow-y: scroll;

     }
```

Comment: Dónde está el código? Qué has intentado hasta ahora? Te da algún error? [Investiga](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2878#2878) e [inténtalo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2874#2874)

Comment: Solo tengo el div con scroll y css para el tamaño pero no tengo idea de como agregar las miniaturas y hacer que se haga auto scroll dependiendo de la miniatura seleccionada

Comment: Creo que lo que quieres hacer es que al darle click a la imagen miniatura (una de las 3 chicas) te lleve a la mas grande y segun corresponda. ¿es eso?

Comment: @BrianMartinez asi es

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La respuesta a tu pregunta es la mas basica de **html**. esto se realiza con un **identificador** (*ID*) la cual tienes que ubicar en la foto de destino (`id="foto1"`), ahora tienes que ir a esa foto con la etiqueta `<a href=""></a>` al cual le agregaras el identificador `#foto1`. el codigo queda algo haci:

```
<div class="col-md-5 mx-auto gallery-res">
    <div class="min" style="display:block;margin: auto;float: left;">
        <a href="#foto1"><img width="20%" src="../img/cc1.jpg" alt=""></a>
            <br>
        <a href="#foto2"><img width="20%" src="../img/cc1.jpg" alt=""></a>
            <br>
        <a href="#foto3"><img width="20%" src="../img/cc1.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div class="anyClass bg-gray" style="max-height: 800px;float: right;">
        <div class="btn-center mt-5">
            <img id="foto1" width="80%" src="../img/cc1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="btn-center mt-2">
            <img id="foto2" width="80%" src="../img/cc2.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="btn-center mt-2">
            <img id="foto3" width="80%" src="../img/cc3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Te acomode algunos estilos para facilitarte el trabajo, tu mismo puedes editarlo a tu gusto!.

**no olvides que si mi respuesta te sirvio marques tu pregunta como respondida**

Comment: Eres un genio, gracias